# How to find angular position and distance of Estimote iBeacon against iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ibeacon, estimote

I have been working on Estimote beacons SDK for creating application in which I have putted 6 estimote beacons on 6 different meeting hall. And I can get distance (in meter) of all beacons from the iPhone which contains my app. To get distance of all beacons I am using this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Distance Demo";

    /*
     * BeaconManager setup.
     */
    self.beaconManager = [[ESTBeaconManager alloc] init];
    self.beaconManager.delegate = self;

    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:self.beacon.proximityUUID


    [self.beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.beaconManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

#pragma mark - ESTBeaconManager delegate

- (void)beaconManager:(id)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
    CLBeacon *firstBeacon = [beacons firstObject];

    [self updateDotPositionForDistance:firstBeacon.accuracy];
}

#pragma mark -

- (void)updateDotPositionForDistance:(float)distance
{
    NSLog(@"distance: %f", distance);

}
```

But I need the exact angular position of all beacons from iPhone device (which contains my app). Actually I want my app result like this image:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Im afraid this is 'a bit' too broad for SO -- SO is more Q&A style for concrete technical issues and this is not even really a programming issue (broadness aside) but a mathematical issue

Comment: Estimote has an indoor location SDK to solve your problem. Granted it doesn't work too well from my experience but you may be able to use their code as a launching pad or as a reference. Here's a link to the GitHub repo: https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-Indoor-SDK

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution neither in Core Location nor in the original Estimote SDK to get angular position of beacons or the user in relation to beacons (there is a tool separate from the legacy SDK though, explained below). You can, however, implement triangulation to use the distance measurements and fixed positions of beacons to figure out the angles. Keep in mind though that without a lot of noise reduction, the measurements will fluctuate a lot, due to the nature of radio waves. So if you want this to work reliably, there's a lot of math to do.

At Estimote, we also have and Indoor Location SDK which was designed to map locations and provide indoor navigation solutions. We're still working on making improvements to the accuracy and stability of positioning: we've released a couple of major update since the launch in October 2014, but there's still space for imporvement. It should be more than enough to take you off the ground, so feel free to check it out here: http://estimote.com/indoor/

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

a broad answer to a broad question:

if you know the relative position of the beacons between them -- you can place them given the user position ... the user position you could triangulate if you see 3 beacons.

BUT

this won't work because you won't have the exact distances to the beacons. You may think you do but beacons fluctuate so wildly that this isn't possible